# Required Database Permissions for Tridion 2013

Tags: database, installation, permissions

I am providing a SQL Server for Tridion 2013.  I don't have the installation media yet, but I understand this will create the database logins and users.  Could anyone tell me the minimum permissions required on the database for these objects.  I would like to apply as little permissions as required.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for database server pre-requisites is available [HERE](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1#docid=GUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E55DBE7E-E436-4899-AC75-B412BCC16D69).
For installation and configuration of the content manager database, Tridion recommends a MTSUser. Configuration of SQL server is available [HERE](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1#docid=GUID-1E8C5BC2-B755-4038-86B2-8DDA5AE2E6EA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-1E8C5BC2-B755-4038-86B2-8DDA5AE2E6EA.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-1E8C5BC2-B755-4038-86B2-8DDA5AE2E6EA).

I would also note that Tridion uses a database for Content Data Store (Tridion Broker) and also Experience Manager (WYSIWYG editor).

Installation is typically done using PowerShell. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on which databases you will be responsible for. In any case, the installation scripts will grant default permissions and the minimum requirements are documented in various 'database security' sections of the documentation. For example:

- [Content Manager database security settings](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-AFA7DB02-227C-4D07-A2F7-44EAB604C272)
- [Audience Manager and Outbound E-mail database security settings](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-226EC724-6ECB-48BD-9AE5-1EF538AAE59C)